# Add/remove MySQL column to existing table via PHP / PDO with user defined name and datatype

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, alter-table, alter

I want users of my PHP web app to be able to insert columns into some tables without requiring somebody with SQL knowledge. What is the best way to do this, obviously SQL injection and id-10-t errors are a concern.

Can I just use

```
sql = 'ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ? ?'
```

and then pass in say 'new_col' and 'varchar(100)' as strings? Or is this outside the abilities of PDO?

Comment: PDO won't be able to bind those as params. I would recommend instead validating the column name against a regular expression that only permits `^[a-z0-9_]+$`, which protects the table name from SQL injection, and allow only selectable options for the data type, also verified against an array of acceptable values in your code.

Comment: if you make the first comment an answer I'll mark it as best, can you explain that regex pattern though? I would like to allow only letters, numbers and underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind the column name or properties in an `ALTER TABLE` statement with PDO parameters, unfortunately.  Instead, as protection from SQL injection, I would recommend validating the column name against a regular expression which permits only letters, numbers, and underscores, and be sure to backquote the column name in the statement.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_]+$/i', $column_name)) {
  // Fail!!! submitted column name doesn't match regex
}
```

- `^` = beginning of the string
- `[a-z0-9_]+` = one or more letters, numbers, underscore
- `$` = end of the string
- `/i` = case-insensitive

Next, to verify the column's data type, you should only allow a specific set of options, and validate them with an array. This is called a *whitelist*.

```
// Allowed types:
$acceptable_types = array('VARCHAR(200)', 'VARCHAR(10)', 'INT', 'FLOAT', 'etc...');
if (!in_array($column_data_type, $acceptable_types)) {
  // Fail!!! Invalid type submitted
}
```

The above options would best be served via something like a `<select>` list.  You could also specify additional options like `NULL / NOT NULL` as checkbox inputs to construct the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

```
// Only after everything is successfully validated:
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `$valid_column_name` $valid_column_datatype $NULL_option";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a meta table for the additional columns.

If you have set data present for every kind of car (like curb weight, height, etc) and then other specialized information the user adds, that DOESN'T apply to every car, you can store it in a separate table, like so:

CAR TABLE:
id
name
curb_weight
height
...

META TABLE:
id (primary key)
car_id (foreign key)
data_name
data_value

The Meta table has a one-to-many relationship with the Car table. If a user wants to add a column for 2 particular cars to record "size of mirror" or something, the Meta table would get two records with the automatic id, id of the car, 'Size of Mirror', and the size.

If you wanted to have a set list of data names, you could use a third table, and have the meta table store the id, car_id, and data_id.

Just an idea!

Answer (score -2):

The best way would be obviously **NOT** to allow users to be able to insert columns into some tables. Especially without requiring somebody with SQL knowledge.
This is against all rules.

The combination of such a rather basic question with extremely unusual goal always have a smell of a bad design.

So, the proper answer would be:

1. Quit this idea of user-added columns. It's really weird one.
2. Start another question, explain your overall goal, describe use cases and ask for the proper solution.

Comment: The database is for storing details about cars. The goal is to have the system flexible... obviously all information like curb weight, height, etc is stored in separate columns (unlike before where the entire thing was mashed into one giant field). if for example they decide they want to store valve-train details 6 months from now they can just add in the column and keep going.

Obviously certain columns are locked and only some admins will have permissions but I think for intelligent people with a much better knowledge of the automotive industry than programming it will be acceptible

Comment: if nothing else, it makes it easier for me in the long run and I've enjoyed the opportunity to show off a bit. the page also allows display name, display units, data type/field length, column description (for use in tooltips) and whether the field is visible to admins and/or clients